# Forloop express routing in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, for-loop, routes

Simply: I want to do a forloop of routes with incrementing numbers in their URL since I am expecting to have around 100 entries with the same format.

Without the forloop:

```
app.get('/day1', (req, res) =>{
  res.render('pages/day1/day1.ejs')
});

app.get('/day2', (req, res) =>{
  res.render('pages/day2/day2.ejs')
});

app.get('/day3', (req, res) =>{
  res.render('pages/day3/day3.ejs')
});
```

I've tried this forloop:

```
for(i=1; i<4; i++){
  app.get('/day' + i.toString(), (req,res) =>{
    res.render('pages/day'+ i.toString() +'/day' + i.toString())
  })
};
```

This forloop "works", but only for the last pass of the forloop (in this case for '/day3').

In this scenario:
For '/day2' and '/day1' I get a "Cannot GET /day2" or "Cannot GET /day1".

Even worse, if I try to play around with the initial parameters of the forloop, let's say (i=2;i<3;i++), I get weird behaviors like the /day3 link redirecting me to the /day4 link when it should not even be included.

Does this have something to do with my browser cache history?

Comment: `i` has changed value by the time the callback runs but is used inside the callback. So that won't work.

Comment: I wounder, should you use `let` `(for( let i < 0 ...)`  keyword to iterate over (otherwise use closure / invoke res.render in function (iife) or smt :) ), otherwise maybe learning  some concepts of js is good :)

Comment: you are following wrong case, I suggest you change route to `app.get('day/:id')`. so you can get the no of day in `req. params`. after then you can do, `let day=req.params.id ` `{res.render(``pages/day${day}/day${day}.ejs``)}`. no need of for loop.

Comment: More to that: `https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html` has all cases for express routing - you can use wildcard routes' portion (*), regexp in routing, routes' params and so on...

Answer (score 2):

You are following wrong apporch,

here, by Changing Route to somthing like this,

```
app.get('/day/:id', (req, res) =>{
let day = req.params.id
// use the template string 
res.render(`pages/day${day}/day${day}.ejs`)
});
```

api call will be ( just example if you are using axios at client side ),
API_URL will be your backend app url,

```
axios.get(`${API_URL}/day/1`)
```

you will get desired output according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

No sane person loops routes like this. You'd want to employ dynamic routing like this:

```
app.get('/:day', (req , res) => {
  const { day } = req.params
  res.render(`pages/${day}/${day}.ejs`)
})
```

If you truly want to do it your way, you could try building an array first like this:

```
const days = []

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    days.push("day" + i.toString())
}
```

Then build the routes:

```
days.forEach(day => {
    app.get("/" + day, (req, res) => {
        res.render(`pages/${day}/${day}.ejs`)
    })
})
```